# Create new rolling mean column with GroupBy on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with 11 columns, one of which `date` is an index. I'm trying to create a new column with the rolling mean of the column `total`. However, I get the error: TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':['2016-04-01','2016-05-01','2016-07-01','2016-08-01','2016-09-01',  '2019-04-01','2019-05-01','2019-06-01','2019-08-01','2019-09-01'],
    'Country':['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA','USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA'],
    'Region':['Eastern','Eastern','Eastern','Eastern','Eastern','Eastern','Eastern','Eastern','Eastern','Eastern'],
    'State':['New York','New York','New York','New York','New York','New York','New York','New York','New York','New York'],
    'Supplier':['ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC'],
    'Location':['Bin-1', 'Bin-1', 'Bin-1', 'Bin-1', 'Bin-1','Bin-1', 'Bin-1', 'Bin-1', 'Bin-1', 'Bin-1'],
    'Year':[2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019],
    'Month':[4,5,7,8,9,4,5,6,8,9],
    'periodcode':[4,5,7,8,9,4,5,6,8,9],
    'Product':['bike','bike','bike','bike','bike','bike','bike','bike','bike','bike'],
    'total':[0,2000,1000,4000,0,2000,2000,1000,4000,600]})
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

df['mean'] = df.groupby(['Country','Region','State','Supplier','Location','Product'], as_index=False)['total'].rolling(3).mean().reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
df.head(10)
```

However, when I include the `year` column to the `groupby` i.e.

```
df['mean'] = df.groupby(['Country','Region','State','Supplier','Location','Product','Year'], as_index=False)['total'].rolling(3).mean().reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
```

I get the rolling mean calculated. Issue with this is, I want the grouping to exclude the `Year`

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to calculate? Which "mean" do you want to see in each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since per our discussion in the comments below you would like to calculate the rolling mean per group across years, the following should give you the desired result:

```
df['mean'] = df.groupby(['Country','Region','State','Supplier','Location','Product'])['total'].rolling(3).mean().reset_index().set_index("date")['total']
```

The key is to keep the `date` index (which allows you to match the calculated rolling mean to a row in the original dataframe) and extract the `Series` object returned from the rolling mean calculation on column `total`.

**More detailed explanation:**

Your issue is that the `groupby` without the `Year` results in a `DataFrame` which is incompatible to `df` and therefore cannot be assigned to `df["mean"]`.

The first variant gives a `Series` witch matching index:

```
df.groupby(['Country','Region','State','Supplier','Location','Product','Year'], as_index=False)['total'].rolling(3).mean().reset_index(level=0,drop=True)

date
2016-04-01            NaN
2016-05-01            NaN
2016-07-01    1000.000000
2016-08-01    2333.333333
2016-09-01    1666.666667
2019-04-01            NaN
2019-05-01            NaN
2019-06-01    1666.666667
2019-08-01    2333.333333
2019-09-01    1866.666667
Name: total, dtype: float64
```

However, the second variant (without `Year`) results in a `DataFrame` where each of the entries in the `date` column becomes its own column. Hence, you cannot assign it to `df["mean"]`.

The solution to this issue really depends on the problem you're trying to solve. However, conceptually, if you have `date` as your index, there can only be a single value for each `date` in the `Series` you assign to `df["mean"]`.

Comment: The entire data-set has over 100k records with varying  regions, states, suppliers, locations, products and years. I want to run the rolling mean based on those fields. Thought I could be able to merge the series back to the dataframe using the index (date) field

Comment: You can certainly do that! What I currently don't know is why you want to exclude the year from the `groupby`. Intuitively, I'd assume that you want to have the rolling mean _per year_, but that does not seem to be the case here? In order to add the mean back to `df`, each and every `date` needs to get at most one single value.

Comment: Well, the simple reason I'm excluding it is because the totals in November and December are needed to calculate the mean in January. Otherwise, I end up with a NAN. The rolling mean is used in a subsequent calculation. I want to be able to allow the end user to increase or decrease the rolling window. Hope this clarifies it

Comment: I see. I added a possible solution to my answer. It can probably be tweaked a bit, but with the test data you gave it appears to return the desired result.